# Ajax Url Wordpress with parameter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Im making a filter dropbox to show and change current post per page.
Here is my code:

```
      <select name="order" id="orderBy">
        <option value="date" selected="selected">News</option>
        <option value="orderByFeatured">Featured News</option>
        <option value="orderByViews">Most viewed posts</option>
      </select>
      <select name="showposts" id="viewPostCount">
        <option value="12" selected="selected">Views : Default</option>
        <option value="2">Views : 2</option>
        <option value="3">Views : 3</option>
        <option value="8">Views : 8</option>
        <option value="16">Views : 16</option>
        <option value="20">Views : 20</option>
      </select>

  jQuery('#orderBy,#viewPostCount').change(function () {
    var orderBy = jQuery('#orderBy').val();
    var viewPostCount = jQuery('#viewPostCount').val();

    var targetURL = 'http://localhost/wordpress/category/tin-tuc/?order=' + orderBy + '&showposts=' + viewPostCount + ' #listPosts';
    jQuery('#listPosts').html('<div id="listPosts"><div class="waiting" style="height:300px;"></div></div>').load(targetURL);
  })
```

But it's not work.Look like the url example: http://localhost/wordpress/category/tin-tuc/?order=date&showposts=5#listPosts wont work.It's still show 10 posts (default wp setting) and i had only 10 posts.
How can i make it work?Tks for your help!

Comment: Are you loading the entire output of the page into the #listPosts div? It's not wise at all. Read about using Ajax with Wordpress (there's a built-in option for that purpose).

Comment: Yes if the url work i think it's should show the output into #listPosts div but even i type that url on web browser it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ajax with WordPress requires some specific steps to be followed as mentioned here: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Mainly the following:

1. `add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );`

Above should be added for every ajax call.

2. In your ajax request, you need to pass the parameter:

`var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'orderBy': jQuery('#orderBy').val(),
            'viewPostCount': jQuery('#viewPostCount').val()
        };`

You need to pass this along with other data, like in your case, viewPostCount & orderBy .

3. Your ajax function should be named `my_action_callback` as is added in the `add_action`.

   `function my_action_callback() {
   // do whatever
   wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
   }`